# Typo3 HTTP to HTTPS backend not accessible

Tags: .htaccess, http, https, typo3, backend

After trying to switch from http to https I cannot access the typo3 backend and frontend anymore. The browser only shows blank pages.
The install tool is still accessible, however.

My question is: **How can I revert all changes?**

The only things I did was ...

1) adding the following lines to the `.htaccess` file in the root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

2) and setting `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS[BE][lockSSL] = 2` (default was = 0).

Version: `TYPO3 CMS 6.2.0`

Comment: If you get a blank page, then either the server does not respond properly or PHP throws an error which is suppressed. In any case you should check your server logs.

Comment: Do you know where I usually find this log file?

Comment: That depends on the server operating system and specific setup. Also usually your hosting provider tells you where to look or provides other means to access the logs.

Answer (score 0):

For reverting, you just have to remove the added lines in the `.htaccess` and set `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS[BE][lockSSL] = 0` (eg via FTP or SSH)